# Put block elements into a link tag IE 8, IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

as far as I know there is no problem at all with browsers to render some markup like this:

```
<a href="link.html">
  <h1> some headline </h1>
  <p> some text </p>
  <img src="someImage.png" alt="some image">
</a>
```

apparently IE 8 and IE 9 do have some issues. To an a-tag around those elements causes problems when I'm opening up the page. All elements are shifted and not on the position where they should be. Anything you know about that and how to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set your `a` element's styling to have `display: block`?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly no change here, I have a default link. Should I?

Comment: By default, `a` elements are styled as `display: inline`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I know, but why is this causing issues? I wanna leave it inline.

Comment: Could you create a Code Snippet showing what your problem is? I really don't understand your question as you haven't actually outlined the problem. Your elements are shifted how? Where should they be positioned?

Comment: `display:inline-block` for the link should help. (If it doesn’t, then please be more specific about your issue and what you actually want.)

Comment: @MrAnonymous That is a different issue. If you want to ask about that here, you should ask a new question. Oh, and this site is not a good place to "generate some conversation".

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I composed a quick demo which wraps the topic anchor in inline, inline-block, and block divs.  Above, you'll see a comparison between Firefox (background) and IE8 (foreground).  The inline div kind-of behaved as though it was floated left.  I did not see any appreciable difference between IE8, Firefox, or Chrome.
online demo:  https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XWG93OFhROGNSaEE/MeesterLeester.html
@supersize.  Does this answer your question?  Or, maybe you could tweak this demo to illustrate your concern.